# Download folders and sub folders without files

Tags: linux, wget

How can i download or clone a copy of all the folders and its sub directories from an ftp without the files themselves?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `spider` option in `wget` that will skip the files and only create the directories:

```
wget --recursive --spider ftp://$source
```

The command `man wget` is usually a good resource for this kind of thing, but is rather unclear when describing this particular option (saying something about how this makes wget behave like a web spider to check if a file exists without downloading it).

In contrast, the command `wget --help` **is** very helpful, and for the `--spider` command it says:

```
don't download anything
```